# how to update & access session data on every page in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: session, laravel-5.4

I am writing code for fetching the count of 'alerts' from 'alerts' table and I want to show that alerts count in the menu that is obviously presented in "/layouts/app.blade.php". for this I am using sessions like after user logs in I am adding a session data to the existing session like below:

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUser.php

protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    /*** I have added the session here ***/
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    $count = DB::table('alerts')
            ->where('acknowledged', 1)
            ->count();
    $request->session()->put('count_alert', $count);
    /***** END's here ******/

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

I am showing that session in /resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php

```
$value = Session::get('count_alert');
<a href="{{ url('/alerts') }}"> echo ' ('.$value.') '; </a>
```

Its working fine till now but if user updates the alerts then count will be changed then I have to maintain that count through entire application as because it has to be shown in the layouts app.blade.php file. **Means on Page refresh I need to update that session and show in the menu(header)**. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Page refresh reloads the current `route`. You should get & set alert count within the `method` which shows this view. So everytime this page is loaded. You will get the latest alert count.

For example. Your view is `user.index` which is returned when you visit a named route `user.index`

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
  //Get the alert count
  $alert_count = DB::table('alerts')->count();

  return view('user.index',[
       'alert_count' => $alert_count,
   ]);
}
```

Once you have sent this count to view. you can do this

```
//user.index.blade.php
 {{ $alert_count }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is not exactly answer I wanted because You said solution only for single route but I want it for every route, every page that is throughout the application.

Comment: In that case, Middleware is the solution. You can set up a middleware with same functionality and add this middleware to any number of routes you want

Comment: Thanks but I didn't understand. I know little bit about middleware not briefly. could you plz explain bit briefly.